# Does this model fit into hadoop correctly?

Tags: hadoop, word-count

I need to know if my use case is correctly structured for hadoop. Assume that I wanted to run the word count jar on a hadoop cluster, but I want my output sorted such that each output file only has the words that have the same starting letter.

I believe that I can use the partitioner class, to sort to different reducers based on the first letter of the word. And I think that have 26 reducers one for each letter should get the out put the way I want. But I need to know if this is possible and or correct way to approach such a type of problem with regards to hadoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this would be the simplest way of doing it - one reducer per starting letter.  As you say, you'll need a simple custom partioner to route the map phase output correctly.